# fab server not working — socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: python, homebrew, fabric

When running fab server, I'm getting an error:

```
$ fab server

* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
*args, **kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 419, in execute
results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jonathantuck/Desktop/website/fabfile.py", line 8, in server
app.run(port = 80, debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 706, in run_simple
test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Not sure what I did wrong. Is it how I configured it? I googled around and couldn't find anything. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT (when running sudo):

```
$sudo fab server
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
*args, **kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 419, in execute
results['<local-only>'] = task.run(*args, **new_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 174, in run
return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/jonathantuck/Desktop/website/fabfile.py", line 8, in server
app.run(port = 80, debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 706, in run_simple
test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

EDIT 2 (when running "sudo lsof -i :80"):

```
$ sudo lsof -i :80
Password:
COMMAND    PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    8522 jonathantuck   84u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be8004b79f      0t0  TCP 10.0.13.151:51920->stackoverflow.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    8522 jonathantuck  128u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be7dce379f      0t0  TCP 10.0.13.151:51913->stackoverflow.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google    8522 jonathantuck  129u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be7ef83f87      0t0  TCP 10.0.13.151:51915->yv-in-f102.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    8522 jonathantuck  142u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be7dce079f      0t0  TCP 10.0.13.151:51916->a184-26-136-74.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     8721       root    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     8722       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9206       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9207       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9208       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)

$ sudo lsof -i :80
COMMAND    PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    8522 jonathantuck  110u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be8004b79f      0t0  TCP     10.0.13.151:51967->a184-26-136-56.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Google    8522 jonathantuck  129u  IPv4 0x6d0fd4be7ef83f87      0t0  TCP 10.0.13.151:51915->yv-in-f102.1e100.net:http (ESTABLISHED)
httpd     8721       root    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     8722       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9206       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9207       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     9208       _www    5u  IPv6 0x6d0fd4be722abb3f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: You can't run on port `80` because you need to be `root` to do that (for any port less than `1024`). Try `sudo fab server`...

Comment: Getting error still, will post on edit. My bad for not posting that. I had tried that earlier as well :/

Comment: @Jtuck4491 may I give your an advice? When you do your software developing (or any other thing in this life) do not just bruteforce the solutions, instead, try to read and understand what issue is and how to solve it :)

Comment: I really tried. @aspect_mkn8rd -- only problem is nothing I was doing was working and I was going in circles. I tried this earlier and I'd have several things coming up on port 80. I'd kill all of them and they'd come back up. I'm just trying my best to learn. Still not letting me kill them off though.

Comment: @Jtuck4491 what things exactly and how do they comeback? Elaborate on that?